# How to insert integration code for CRM?

Tags: code, customization

I use the CRM (bpm'online) and want to send the registration data directly from the site to CRM. Now I do it via Google Forms. CRM vendor provides the HTML-code that should be installed onto the code of the landing page before tag (/body). The problem is that this solution works for static HTML sites meanwhile Wordpress performs the PHP-code to generate the dynamic html. So, the question is where exactly should I install this code to collect the registration form (Contact Form 7) in CRM? Thanks!

Below is the sample of provided code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://webtracking-v01.bpmonline.com/JS/track-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="https://webtracking-v01.bpmonline.com/JS/create-object.js"></script>
<script>
/**
* Replace the "css-selector" placeholders in the code below with the element selectors on your landing page.
* You can use #id or any other CSS selector that will define the input field explicitly.
* Example: "Email": "#MyEmailField".
* If you don't have a field from the list below placed on your landing, leave the placeholder or remove the line.
*/
var config = {
    fields: {
        "Name": "css-selector", // Name of a visitor, submitting the page
        "Email": "css-selector", // Visitor's email
        "Zip": "css-selector", // Visitor's ZIP code
        "MobilePhone": "css-selector", // Visitor's phone number
        "Company": "css-selector", // Name of a company (for business landing pages)
        "Industry": "css-selector", // Company industry (for business landing pages)
        "FullJobTitle": "css-selector", // Visitor's job title (for business landing pages)
        "UseEmail": "css-selector", // Logical value: 'true' equals to visitor's opt-in to receive emails
        "City": "css-selector", // City
        "Country": "css-selector", // Country
        "Commentary": "css-selector" // Notes
    },
    landingId: "5e90c84e-62b1-4797-a018-5a1ba24d7395",
    serviceUrl: "https://www.link",
    redirectUrl: "http://here is link/"
};
/**
* The function below creates a object from the submitted data.
* Bind this function call to the "onSubmit" event of the form or any other elements events.
* Example: <form class="mainForm" name="landingForm" onSubmit="createObject(); return false">
*/
function createObject() {
    landing.createObjectFromLanding(config)
}
/**
* The function below inits landing page using URL parameters.
*/
function initLanding() {
    landing.initLanding(config)
}
jQuery(document).ready(initLanding)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Create a custom template for your landing page:

```
 /**
 *  Template Name: My landing page
 *
 */
```

and add the code manually as you would add to a static site.

**Option 2**

Create a custom field for your code on the landing page and output the meta content in the template created above.

**Option 3**

Write a conditional statement in your header file testing for the landing page and insert the snippet.

```
if (is_page( 'Landing Page' )) {

//do stuff
```